# Rails 3- Retrieve last N records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model that collects financial data from my clients each calendar quarter of each year (so :quarter 1, 2, 3, and 4 for any given :year). For simplicity, the model is called Quarter and has :client_id, :quarter, :year, and :amount attributes. I want to be able to query and display the last four entries for the :amount attribute based on the quarter that is currently being displayed.

So for example, if I'm looking at :quarter 3 for :year 2011, then I want to show the :amount for the current quarter (which is easy), as well as the :amount for :quarter 2 & 1 for :year 2011, and :quarter 4 for :year 2010. Does that make sense?

I made this work by assigning a different variable to each record that I want to retrieve, then using elsif statements to find it, but I know there has to be a cleaner way to do it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with the Rails 2.x query interface the answer is:

```
Quarter.find(:all, :order => :year, :limit => 4).reverse
```

with the Rails 3.x query interface the answer is:

```
Quarter.order(:by => :year).limit(4).reverse
```

btw. I think you should not store your data in a model called "Quarter" , but rather in a model called "FinancialData" and have that model have an attribute "quarter" which would contain 2011/1, 2011/2,  or havt two attributes :year and :quarter which need to be indexed together

See also:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

Comment: Cool man, thanks. Sorry I'm really pretty new at this, how then would I put this in my view to show just the entries for the :amount attribute?

Comment: check this web-site: http://railscasts.com/ -- it has really useful episodes -- some at beginner level, some at advanced level.  Maybe search for "View" there.

Comment: Thanks again Tilo. What I had done was just assign a variable to this query in my controller, something like: @lastfouritems = query, then displayed that variable in my view. What it does though is show all the attributes for my model in a huge list, instead of just the :amount attribute. How do I isolate this one attribute and only show that?

Comment: @lastfouritems[i].amount , where i = 0..3 , or you can use an each loop to go through the Array.

If you want to have an array with the amounts only, you can do @lastfouritems.map(&:amount)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot, but so far I'm 90% of the way there.

Comment: The ".map" solution gives me an array displayed like "[4,3,2,1]". So that answers my question perfectly! Now I just need to figure out how to plot that on my charts (highcharts). Not sure if that will be to plot just that one variable @lastfouritems or something different.

Answer (score 8):

To retrieve last N records :

```
Quarter.last(n).reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

```
User.all.order("id desc").limit(40)
```